# Looping the values in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, split

i have this function

```
var globalvar = new Array();
function coor(coor1){

    for(i=0;i<=coor1.length;i++){
        exy = coor1[i].split(".");
        ex = exy[0].split("-");
        ey = exy[1].split("-");

        for(x=parseInt(ex[0]);x<=parseInt(ex[1]);x++){

            for(y=parseInt(ey[0]);y<=parseInt(ey[1]);y++){

                globalvar.push(ex[x]+"."+ey[y]);
            }
        }

    }
}

// execute function
coor(["5-7.8-9","1-2.3-4"]);
```

what i expect is...

the `globalvar` variable will have this values in an array

```
globalvar = ["5.8","5.9","6.8","6.9","7.8","7.9","1.3","1.4","2.3","2.4"];
```

i hope anyone can help me figure this thing... Y_Y coz when i use my current code, it will return `empty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though Arun's answer works, it is leaking globals all over the place.

Generally, you want to keep the global space clear to prevent issues later.

Might I recommend:

```
function coor(c) {
  for(var i = 0, l = c.length; i < l; i++) {
    var xy = c[i].split('.')
      , x  = xy[0].split('-')
      , y  = xy[1].split('-');
    for(var xi = ~~x[0]; xi <= ~~x[1]; xi++) {
      for(var yi = ~~y[0]; yi <= ~~y[1]; yi++) {
        globalvar.push(xi + '.' + yi);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Preferably though, you wouldn't have a function write to a global variable in the first place. In which case, you would have the function return the results, and you can do with those results as you need.

For Example:

```
function coor(c) {
  var r = [];
  for(var i = 0, l = c.length; i < l; i++) {
    var xy = c[i].split('.')
      , x  = xy[0].split('-')
      , y  = xy[1].split('-');
    for(var xi = ~~x[0]; xi <= ~~x[1]; xi++) {
      for(var yi = ~~y[0]; yi <= ~~y[1]; yi++) {
        r.push(xi + '.' + yi);
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}


var globalvar = [];
var results = coor(['5-7.8-9','1-2.3-4']);
globalvar = globalvar.concat(results);
```

Comment: this time, i prefer your answer more sir... it's better... i forgot about the issue of leaking variables into the outside of the function... thanks for the help... XD

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
var globalvar = new Array();
function coor(coor1){
    for(i=0;i<coor1.length;i++){ //Removed =
        exy = coor1[i].split(".");
        ex = exy[0].split("-");
        ey = exy[1].split("-");
        for(x=parseInt(ex[0]);x<=parseInt(ex[1]);x++){
            for(y=parseInt(ey[0]);y<=parseInt(ey[1]);y++){
                console.log(y)
                globalvar.push(x+"."+y); //need to use x & y not ex[x] & ey[y]
            }
        }
    }
}
coor(["5-7.8-9","1-2.3-4"])
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s8YnE/)

Answer (score 0):

Sth like this should work

```
function floatRange(delim, rangedelim) {
    var result = [];
    var args = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 2);
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        var cur = args[i].toString().split(delim);
        console.log(cur)
        var floats = [cur[0].split(rangedelim), cur[1].split(rangedelim)];
        console.log(floats)
        for (var j = floats[0][0]; j <= floats[0][1]; j++) {

            for (var k = floats[1][0]; k <= floats[1][1]; k++) {
                result.push(Number(j + "." + k));


            }
        }
        console.log(result)
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(floatRange(".", "-", "4-6.5-8", "6-7.8-9")); //[4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.8, 6.9, 7.8, 7.9]
```

Heres an [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uxenex/1/edit) Example